# Select from position to end of line in string

Tags: php, string

Let's say I've got a string `"blbl\nblbl etc"`. I know I should start at position `$pos`. I've got to select everything to the end of the line. I can't use this:

```
substr($string, $pos, strpos($string, "\n", $pos))
```

Mac doesn't use `\n` as a delimiter. What should I do?

Comment: OS X does use `\n` for newline.  Only System 9 and earlier use `\r` instead, and if you actually have users on System 9 (or are on System 9 yourself), then you have much bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: What's the source of the string (meaning is it user supplied or system generated, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the string through a function which replaces \r\n or \r with \n first.  It's worth doing as a matter of course, unless you actually want to preserve platform specific line endings.

FWIW Mac's use \n now anyway.

Answer (score 18):

It should be :

```
substr($string, $pos, ( strpos($string, PHP_EOL, $pos) ) - $pos);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try the `PHP_EOL` constant:

```
substr($string, $pos, strpos($string, PHP_EOL, $pos));
```

It contains the end-of-line character sequence of the OS the script is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process each individual line in the string you can always split the string into a array. You can do this using preg_split() in a way that will identify more than systems end of line character.

```
$lines = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $string);
```